# How to add methods to the object literal being assigned to the variable c, so that the type-checking is satisfied?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to satisfy the type checking in the code snippet below ?

```
interface Counter {
    getCount: () => number
    increment: (n: number) => void
}
let c: Counter = {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
let c: Counter = {
    getCount: () => 1,
    increment: (n: number) => {}
}
```